# NGINX: replacing React router hash routes

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have following **nginx** config:

```
server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /home/example/develop/frontend/build;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/#(.*)$ $1 last;  # for some reason this is not working
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I've changed from React [HashRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) to [BrowserRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter), so I had to add those 2 location entries. Some of the links outside application are already generated, so I would like to redirect all hash urls to standard browser urls to make my app backward compatible, e.g.:

```
https://dev.example.com/#/somepage/123123
```

should be changed (or should redirect) to:

```
https://dev.example.com/somepage/123123
```

For some reason, none of the `rewrite` rules I have written seems to work.

Comment: Anything from the `#` onwards is only seen by the browser. It is never sent to the web server. Nginx cannot help you.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for this. I've managed to find a solution after locating exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RichardSmith mention in comment, everything after `#` is processed by a browser, so it is never sent to the **NGINX**.

I've managed to solve this issue on the app client side.

My app routing looks like this:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
    <UserContextProvider>
        <React.Suspense fallback={ loading }>
            <Switch>
                {/* routes */ }
            </Switch>
        </React.Suspense>
    </UserContextProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Solution:**

In `UserContextProvider` I've placed following code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (location.hash.startsWith('#/')) { // checking if it's HashRoute
        history.replace({
            pathname: location.hash.replace(/#\/(.*)/, '$1'), // skipping `#/`
        })
    }
}, [])
```

After this change all the `#` routes are "translated" into `BrowserRoutes` and it works as expected, what means that my app is backward compatible with previously used `HashRouter`.